# Programmatically determine if application is the MarketPlace version

Tags: android, marketplace

I have an application that's offered in and outside of the MarketPlace.

Is there a way of determining from within the code where the application came from?

I've got a few indirect methods ...

1) I could simply infer from whether they have "Allow installation of non-Market applications" ticked ...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS

2) Or I could just make separate builds and make it explicit in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it explicit in the `android:versionName` of each release.

And if the code is available for people to compile their own APKs, set the `android:versionName` to "custom" and just change it temporarily when building for the Market.

Answer (score 4):

If [`PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) returns `com.google.android.feedback` for your application, then it was installed by the Android Market.

Comment: This is not reliable - I've also seen `com.android.vending` returned for Market-installed apps. However, it should be safe to assume that it was not installed by the market if `null` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Market application won't even know where an application came from when you wipe its cache, I very much doubt there is any other way to find out.